# objective-c/iphone sdk newcomer question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

At present I'm building a basic application to learn Objective-C and the iPhone SDK.
I'm creating NSObject with getters and setters to get to grips with how these works. I've successfully added a property and getters and setters to my main controller, currently I'm trying to create a separate class which I can create a new instance of within my controller but it crashes when I try and use the setter.

Thank you in advance for your time, sorry if this question is as stupid as I'm sure it is.

Here's the header for my class

QuizQuestion.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface QuizQuestion : NSObject {
    NSString *question;
}

@property (retain) NSString* question;


@end
```

QuizQuestion.m

```
#import "QuizQuestion.h"

@implementation QuizQuestion

@synthesize question;



- (void) dealloc
{
    [question release];

    [super dealloc];
}



@end
```

And here is my controller code (i've cut some out)

```
@implementation Quiz2ViewController
@class QuizQuestion; // Is this correct?
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    QuizQuestion *aQuestion;
      //gets here fine, but crashes (the app closes) when I set question.
      [aQuestion setQuestion:@"hello world"];
      [super viewDidLoad];
} 
@end
```

As well as @class I tried import "QuizQuestion.h" and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate space and initialize the QuizQuestion.

```
QuizQuestion *aQuestion = [[QuizQuestion alloc] init];
```

before setting the question.

Comment: Say it like you mean it! :) Note that OP will either need to `release` or `autorelease` said object, too.

Comment: lol sorry. YOU HAVE TO ALLOCATE SPACE AND INITIALIZE THE QUIZ QUESTION FIRST! =)  and yes you're right you have to release or autorelease the object too. =)

Comment: Great, now it's working. I think I need to read some more basic Objective-C stuff before I go any further.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually allocating an instance of the QuizQuestion class—your `aQuestion` variable isn’t pointing to anything in particular, so trying to send it a message, like `-setQuestion:`, is sending that message to... well, there’s no telling where, and sending things messages that aren’t meant for them is a surefire way to crash your app. What you need to do is this:

```
QuizQuestion *aQuestion = [[QuizQuestion alloc] init];
[aQuestion setQuestion:@"hello world"];
```

You also need to call `[aQuestion release]` at some point, or you’ll leak the memory associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up on some documentation before you try any more coding. Apple has several intro programming guides that are very good. The problem you are having is addressed in this section:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html

Answer (score 0):

```
QuizQuestion *aQuestion = [[QuizQuestion alloc] init];
[aQuestion setQuestion:@"hello world"];
[aQuestion release];
```